# SQL Server - Primary Key of MAX Timestamp row Grouped by Customer and Day of timestamp

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, t-sql, select, aggregate-functions

First off, I saw this question: [SQL MAX of column including its primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611011/sql-max-of-column-including-its-primary-key)
My question differs in that I need more than a single row as I need all the Customer Id's.

I consider myself a competent SQL developer, but I've been dealing with an arcane database design of which I have no control over (but I digress).

I'm looking for more performant methods of getting the primary keys of rows after a filter, max aggregation and a group by.

I'm dealing with versioned tables (meaning many copies of the same row with minor data element changes until it's "Closed").  I need to get the last Closed (Closed = 1) Order of each Customer everyday BETWEEN a time period (OrderDateTime) for a group of "Orders" containing a particular OrderItem (OrderItem = '1111').  I'm not sure if I even understand that. :-)

*Note, for brevity and understandability, I've done my best to convert my use case to generic terms. Orders and OrderItems (as these are fairly academic) instead of what I'm actually hunting for.

Traditionally, I've written something like this.

```
SELECT
    Order.Order_ID
FROM
(
    SELECT
        Customer_ID,
        MAX(OrderedDateTime) AS OrderedDateTime
    FROM
        Order_versioned
    JOIN
        OrderItems_versioned
            ON Order_versioned.OrderID = OrderItems_versioned.OrderID
                AND OrderItem.Item_ID = '1111'
    WHERE
        Order_versioned.Closed = 1
        AND Order_versioned.OrderedDateTime BETWEEN '2012-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-01-31 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY
        Order.Customer_ID
        , CAST(Order.OrderedDateTime AS DATE)
) t1
JOIN
    Order
        ON t1.Customer_ID = Order.Customer_ID
            t1.OrderedDateTime = Order.OrderedDateTime
```

Background: Customer_ID and OrderedDateTime would constitute a unique row, that's why I can Join on them and be confident it's a single row.

Note: There are indexes on Order_versioned.Closed and all *ID columns.

The problem lies in that while Order_versioned.Customer_ID is indexed, Order_versioned.OrderedDateTime is NOT indexed and I cannot (for many reasons... thank you support contracts) add an index.  Needless to say this method takes a while (Only 274,000,000 OrderItems across 20,000,000 Orders).

I could play around with adding more fields that are indexed in my subquery and adding those to my join, but ideally, I want a new methodology.

I'm hoping someone more Jedi than I has some features that I did not know about up their sleeve and could point me in the right direction.  I'm thinking SQL Server's windowing features (OVER, PARTITION, etc.) along with the appropriate aggregation may get me what I need, I'm just not well enough versed with these newer features (Yes, I know they're from 2005).  Then again, this may be the best way to do it given my constraints.  What I am hoping is that SQL Server maintains some kind of internal pointer to the record on a MAX aggregation and I just don't know how to get to it.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help:
I made a small example that uses currency and currency values. I the example the task is to take the latest currency value for a currency. I think that you can apply this example quite easy to your code. So here is the example:

```
DECLARE @tblCurrency TABLE
    (
        pkCurrencyID INT,
        name VARCHAR(100)
    )
DECLARE @tblCurrencyValues TABLE
    (
        pkCurrencyValueID INT,
        currencyDate DATETIME,
        fkCurrencyID INT,
        rate FLOAT
    )

INSERT INTO @tblCurrency
(
    pkCurrencyID,
    name
)
SELECT 1,'SEK' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2,'EURO'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'DKK'

INSERT INTO @tblCurrencyValues
(
    pkCurrencyValueID,
    fkCurrencyID,
    currencyDate,
    rate
)
SELECT 1,1,GETDATE(),1.4
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,1,GETDATE()-2,1.4
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,1,GETDATE()-1,5
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,2,GETDATE(),1.4
UNION ALL
SELECT 5,2,GETDATE()-2,1.4
UNION ALL
SELECT 6,2,GETDATE()-1,5
UNION ALL
SELECT 7,3,GETDATE(),1.4
UNION ALL
SELECT 8,3,GETDATE()-2,1.4
UNION ALL
SELECT 9,3,GETDATE()-1,5

;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY tblCurrencyValues.fkCurrencyID order by tblCurrencyValues.currencyDate) as currencyValueRank,
        tblCurrencyValues.fkCurrencyID,
        tblCurrencyValues.currencyDate,
        tblCurrencyValues.rate
    FROM
        @tblCurrencyValues AS tblCurrencyValues
)
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    CTE
    JOIN @tblCurrency AS tblCurrency
        ON CTE.fkCurrencyID=tblCurrency.pkCurrencyID
WHERE 
    CTE.currencyValueRank=1
```

Answer (score 2):

To take what Arion suggested a step further.  Here is the exact port of what I provided in the original question using windowing and CTE's (Arion's suggestions).

```
;WITH t1
AS
(
    SELECT
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY o.Customer_ID, CAST(o.OrderedDateTime AS Date) ORDER BY o.OrderedDateTime DESC) as iRank
        , o.Order_ID
    FROM
        Order_versioned o WITH(NOLOCK)
    JOIN
        OrderItems_version AS oi WITH(NOLOCK) 
            ON
            o.OrderID = oi.OrderID
            AND oi.Item_ID = '1111'
WHERE
    o.Closed = 1
    AND o.OrderedDateTime BETWEEN '2012-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-01-31 23:59:59'
)
SELECT 
    t1.Order_ID
FROM
    t1
WHERE
    t1.iRank = 1
```

It is very fast. But I'm doing some more investigation to ensure this is yielding the best performance.